# Lock while Oracle constraints are enabled with VALIDATE?

Tags: oracle, locking, constraints

Is there a lock:

1. While the constraint is being changed from *disabled* to *enabled*?
2. And while it is being changed from *novalidate* to *validate*?

[The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#i1010237) says no lock:

> If you change the state of any single constraint from ENABLE
>   NOVALIDATE to ENABLE VALIDATE, the operation can be performed in
>   parallel, and does not block reads, writes, or other DDL operations.

Here it says there is a lock:

> A constraint in a table is defined with the INITIALLY IMMEDIATE
>   clause.  You executed the ALTER TABLE command with the ENABLE VALIDATE
>   option to enable the constraint that was disabled. It prevents insert,
>   update, and delete operations on the table while the constraint is in
>   the process of being enabled.

Comment: Where did you find that second quote, and is that source more official than the official Oracle documentation?

Comment: The second quote comes from an sample of OCA Exam. I'm not sure who make the answer but it is widely accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in the first quote, the constraint is already enabled with novalidate.  Since the constraint is already enabled, all new inserts and updates must conform to the constraint.  During the "enable validate" from an already enabled constraint, historical data is not being changed to violate the constraint (so no read lock required) and new data must conform to the constraint since it is already enabled (so no write lock required).

In the second quote, the constraint is disabled.  Since it is being enabled with validate, it must not add the constraint until after validation succeeds.  Since enabling the constraint may succeed OR fail depending on historical data, insert/update statements do not know whether to check against the constraint until after it is enabled, meaning it must lock until the operation is complete.  The difference between these two is basically whether or not the constraint was disabled when validate was specified.

Here's an example to help illustrate this.  Imagine you run a business, and after a few years you decide you don't want to accept pennies any more.  The first scenario above says you can continue accepting new transactions as long as none of them pay with pennies, and at some point later, you will look through your receipts and see if anyone paid with pennies in the past, but the cashier can keep working regardless.  The second scenario says "if nobody has ever paid with pennies, then I don't want to accept pennies anymore" - and so your cashier has to wait until you check your receipts to see if anyone paid with pennies before he/she knows whether or not to accept a new transaction with pennies, so the cashier puts a lock on the register and goes home until you've done the audit.  I know this isn't the best example, but it's a complicated topic so I hope this helped.